# "Request cannot be processed" when using JHipster Google Social Login

Tags: jhipster, spring-social, google-signin

I am trying to add the social login with google feature to a newly generated JHipster application. I have configured a google project with the client id and client secret and added the correct urls and redirect urls. I have added the 'signin' to the webpack.dev.js server configuration. This is what is currently happening:

[image]

After I select which account I want to use to log in with google I am redirected to a page that says "Your request cannot be processed" with the following url "http://localhost:9060/signin?error=provider#".

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried with port 8080?  I think there's an issue with the Webpack proxy config.  FYI this feature is removed in v5 in favor of Keycloak/Okta Social login

Comment: @JonRuddell It was removed in v5 of JHipster?

Comment: Yes.  For example, Facebook/Twitter don't always return emails and you have to use port 8080 (your issue).  It was buggy, unmaintained, and Keycloak/Okta offer a much-improved user and developer experience.  Here's how to add Social Login to Keycloak/Okta: https://github.com/ruddell/jhipster.github.io/blob/401cde6175a91279ccca5b31048d56b3a0cee876/tips/024_tip_enabling_social_login_with_oauth2.md